# Using Python PuDB debugger with pytest

Tags: python, pytest, pudb

Before my testing library of choice was *unittest*. It was working with my favourite debugger - PuDB. Not Pdb!!!

To use PuDB with *unittest*, I paste `import pudb;pudb.set_trace()` between the lines of code.
I then executed `python -m unittest my_file_test`, where *my_file_test* is module representation of *my_file_test.py* file.

Simply using `nosetests my_file_test.py` won't work - `AttributeError: StringIO instance has no attribute 'fileno'` will be thrown.

With *py.test* neither works:

`py.test my_file_test.py`

nor

`python -m pytest my_file_test.py`

Both throw

> ValueError: redirected Stdin is pseudofile, has no fileno()

How can I use *Pudb* with *py.test*?

Comment: looks like I've found the answer here http://lists.idyll.org/pipermail/testing-in-python/2011-December/004616.html

Simply by adding -s flag will not replace stdin and stdout and debugging will be accessible, i.e. `py.test -s my_file_test.py`

Comment: docs may be also useful here: http://pytest.org/latest/usage.html#setting-a-breakpoint-aka-set-trace

Comment: You can replace `import pudb;pudb.set_trace()` with `import pudb.b`. So cool :p

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Simply by adding the *-s* flag, pytest will not replace [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin)) and [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) and debugging will be accessible, i.e., `pytest -s my_file_test.py` will do the trick.

In documentation provided by ambi, it is also said that previously using *-s* explicitly was required for regular *pdb* too, but now the *-s* flag is implicitly used with the *--pdb* flag.

However, *pytest* does not implicitly support PuDB, so setting -s is needed.

Answer (score 12):

There is now [an adapter library available](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-pudb) to expose a `--pudb` tracing option similar to the `--pdb` one.  The more general `-s` option remains a valid solution for manually placed breakpoints from any debugger, of course.

To use, do `pip install pytest-pudb`, and then execute Pytest via `py.test --pudb`.  Additionally, `import pudb; pudb.set_trace()` functionality is supported without the need for `-s` or `--capture=no` if this adapter is installed.