# How to run pytest with an python debugger with tab completion?

Tags: python, debugging, pytest, pdb, ipdb

### Background

I have been debugging my python scripts for ~2 years with plain `from IPython import embed; embed()`, and it has been working really fine. I just place the command on the line I want to examine, and when running the script I will have full IPython shell with capability for examining variables, defining functions, etc. On top of that, IPython shell comes with variable name tab completion.

Now, instead of always defining the "line of pause" with `from IPython import embed; embed()`, I would like my python scripts pause the execution while running tests, when they encounter an exception.

### Question

How do you run `pytest` in such way, that

1. When an *exception* is raised, it launches python debugger
2. This debugger has *tab completion* for variable names?

### Setup

- Windows 10
- Python 3.6

### Simple failing test

```
# test_somemodule.py
def test_me(some_variable):
    x = 1 + some_variable
    return x


test_me('I am a string')
```

*(No, you do not write tests for pytest like this, but for this exemplary purpose this is just fine.)*

### Solutions that do not work

#### 1. `pytest --pdb` (with no `pdbpp` installed)

This opens the basic [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) shell when it runs to the error. But it has no tab completion.

```
-> x = 1 + some_variable
(Pdb) so[<tab_here_produces_tab>]
```

#### 2. `pytest --pdb` (*with* `pdbpp` installed)

This opens the basic [`pdbpp`](https://pypi.org/project/pdbpp/) shell when it runs to the error. But no tab completion.

```
-> x = 1 + some_variable
(Pdb++) so[<tab_here_produces_tab>]
```

#### 3. `pytest --pdb --pdbcls=IPython.terminal.debugger:Pdb`

This opens the basic [`ipdb`](https://pypi.org/project/ipdb/) shell when it runs to the error. But no tab completion.

```
    103
    104 def test_me(some_variable):
--> 105     x = 1 + some_variable
    106     return x
    107

ipdb> so[<tab_here_produces_tab>]
```

#### 4. `fancycompleter.interact()`

Tried `fancycompleter.interact()` as suggested [here](https://github.com/antocuni/pdb/issues/74), no luck (with `pdb`, `ipdb` and `pdbpp`, `fancycompleter v.0.8` and even [this patched version](https://github.com/antocuni/pdb/issues/74#issuecomment-378729981).).

#### 5. `pytest --pdb -s`

As [Sergey Voronezhskiy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4000827/sergey-voronezhskiy) commented, there is `-s` flag available for `pytest`. However, the tab completion works only partially: If there are multiple options for the same starting character(s), it will print out list of possible variables. This lacks the ability of quickly selecting one of the matching variables (which is available in IPython shell, for example):

[image: example with the -s flag]

Is there a way to make the variable name tab completion work? I would prefer `ipdb` or `pdbpp` over the vanilla `pdb`, but even a working solution with `pdb` is just fine.

Comment: Found some related discussion at https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/4008

Comment: looks like you forgot `-s` option

Comment: Thank you! Did not notice that flag. It's nice solution since it does not add an extra step, but there is the downside that it really does not allow tab completion if there are multiple variable names starting with the same letter(s). It just prints the available options. I will add an example picture.

Comment: Have you tried `pdbpp` recently with latest version of pytest. Tab completion works fine on my machine with pdbpp on pytest.

Comment: Yeah I tried now with `pdbpp 0.10.2` and `pytest 5.4.3` and there is no tab completion. Maybe some other package missing, or it is an issue of Windows / Powershell.

Comment: I had the misfortune of using windows and pdbpp doesn't autocomplete there. I haven't tried other solutions mentioned here.

Comment: Please see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25182812/1581629) helps; basically you `pip install pytest-pudb` and then `pytest ... --pubd`

Answer (score 6):

<sup>This is not the optimal solution, but it's better than nothing. Maybe somebody comes with a better answer. Here is what I did</sup>

### 1. alias `emb` for starting `IPython.embed()`

#### 1.1. Steps

- Made `~/.pdbrc` file (`‪C:\Users\<USER>\.pdbrc`) with following contents

```
alias emb from IPython import embed; embed()
```

#### 1.2. Short explanation

- When `pytest` is ran with `--pdb` flag, it starts standard library pdb, or if installed, pdbpp.
- The standard library
  [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) documentation says:

> If a file **.pdbrc** exists in the user’s home directory or in the current directory, it is **read in and executed as if it had been typed at the debugger prompt.** This is particularly useful for aliases. If both files exist, the one in the home directory is read first and aliases defined there can be overridden by the local file.

### 2. Reminder text for alias (optional)

#### 2.1. Steps

- Installed `pdbpp` (`pip install pdbpp`)
- Made `~/.pdbrc.py`<sup>1</sup> file (`‪C:\Users\<USER>\.pdbrc.py`) with following contents

```
import pdb


class Config(pdb.DefaultConfig):
    def setup(self, pdb):
        print('Use "emb" to enter IPython shell')
```

#### 2.2. Short explanation

The [pdbpp documentation](https://github.com/pdbpp/pdbpp) says that if you create a `~/.pdbrc.py` with a `setup()` method, it will be called when you enter the debugger. Therefore, it is possible to create a script that is called every time you enter `pdbpp` debugging shell.

<sup><sup>1</sup>Note: This one has `.py` extension, while the first one, associated with the builtin pdb, does not.</sup>

### 3. Usage Example

Run `pytest --pdb` (same .py file as in the question). As you can see from the figure, tab completion for the variable `some_variable` works.

[image: tab completion inside IPython shell inside pdbpp]

Comment: Better yet, if you like colour:
alias emb from IPython import embed; embed(colors="neutral")